# Left excluding join (SQL)

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

Im trying to find people who have not opened a mail.. I have all who have opened it, so I just want to exclude them from my main DE "UsableUsers".

UsableUsers = 357.990

HasOpened = 95.813

```
select u.[Email Address] from UsableUsers u
left join HasOpened h
on u.[Email Address] = h.[Email Address]
WHERE h.[Email Address] is null
```

And this gives me 0... I dont want to use filters or measures for this task

Comment: Can you confirm the 2 source tables (UsableUsers & HasOpened) and the destination table, have the column name "Email Address"? Have you run the query in an Automation to confirm it completes successfully?

Comment: @CameronRobert Yes, both have the same fields, including Email Address

Comment: Have you tried running this in an Automation to verify if it is completing successfully? 0 results sounds like it's not running to completion. You could also try an INNER JOIN to return the customers who DID open the email - to verify the data is matching correctly. If it doesn't return all 95,813 records, then the problem is in your data.

Comment: you can try deleting the Target DE and recreating it